# Non Opengl es drawing app that uses tool to draw with?

Tags: opengl-es, core-animation

Apparently asking about glpaint raises the ire of many on stackoverflow, so let me ask the question this way in a non-opengle es way.

I have been look at example app's with source code for drawing (like the painting app in the "iPhone for Programmers An App-Drive Approach). I understand how these apps work. My dilemma is this:

I want to have a tool like a pencil on the screen that jumps to any spot I touch and then when I hold it down and move the pencil tool it draws and then when I stop the pencil remains on the screen. I can make an app that displays and moves the pencil. I can make an app that draws without the pencil. I just can't seem to figure out how to do both at the same time.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a draggable UIImageView on top of the OpenGL ES view work? I have made an app that does this and it works well.